# Return the longest list of consecutive negative numbers using itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Given the series:

```
series = [2, 6, 9, -1, 1, -3, -3, -3, 1,-4]
```

How do you return the list `[-3, -3, -3]` using `itertools.groupby`?

Trying:

```
from itertools import groupby
max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(series, key=lambda i: i < 0)), key=len)
```

returns:

```
[2, 6, 9]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
from itertools import groupby

series = [2, 6, 9, -1, 1, -3, -3, -3, 1, -4]
result = max((list(group) for key, group in groupby(series) if key < 0), key=len)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[-3, -3, -3]
```

The problem with your code is that you are using the wrong key in the groupby,  `key=lambda i: i < 0`, just filter the results if the key is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Check you `k` value for True or False.

```
from itertools import groupby
series = [2, 6, 9, -1, 1, -3, -3, -3, 1,-4]
x = max([list(g) for k, g in groupby(series, key=lambda i: i < 0) if k == True ], key=len)
print(x)
```

Comment: `if k == True ` --> `if k`

Comment: That works if you know you only EVER want to check for True.  You may however decide later to find the other path, in which case substituting True for a variable would instantly make this more flexible.  I like explicit for this reason in this scenario for code review later.

Comment: Sorry @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't understand your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish um, how does that make it any more flexible? you'd still have to edit the source code if you later wanted to modify it. It is generally accepted that using `==` for `True` or `False` is bad style, especially in a conditional. In fact, it is explicitly recommended against in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: ahh, I see what you mean now

Comment: @juanpa this is hardly the example in PEP8.  This is inside an inline comprehension where both values may be asked for.  If you wanted either or, you would end up writing it the way I did.  So how am I wrong?